# Xamarin changing binding context value during runtime

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Please question might be funny, not be funny at all or confusing! But the simple goal I wanted is to changing the value of binding context in xamarin.forms on runtime!!

**IvalueConverter**

```
class LoginFrameHeight : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value / 1.9;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Resource Dictionary**

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:LoginFrameHeight x:Key="frameHeight"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

**Setting Frame Height**

```
   <Frame CornerRadius="15"
      HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference frame},
      Path=Height,Converter={StaticResource frameHeight}}" Padding="0"></Frame>
```

Code works fine! My problem is that I have about **three (3) frames** to apply different HeightRequested using same process! is it possible to change the **(1.9)** in **IvalueConverter** during
runtime, so that I can use the same class **LoginFrameHeight** instead of creating different classes for the frames?

Comment: where does the scaling factor come from?  Is it a property on a bound object, or a hardcoded value for each frame, or something else?

Comment: Hardcoded value

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "YES" you can use ConverterParameter here is quick ref: [This official documentation will show more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)

Example:`<Label Text="{Binding Red,Converter={StaticResource doubleToInt}, ConverterParameter=255, StringFormat='Red = {0:X2}'}" />`

Comment: Thanks!! I tried the process it doesn't gives the actual value, for me to get the frame height I have to divide the value of ivalueconverter by 1.9, which can be replaced with any number though, what I want is how to change that 1.9 in the ivalueconverter during runtime, because I want to set three frames with different height!! And I don't want to create different ivalueconverter class, just want to use one and change the value of 1.9 has it from my code above. Thanks

Comment: That is exactly what he is demonstrating how to do.  converterParameter would be whatever value you need for each case

Comment: @Jason thanks, but I have tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: Hi @AtsenoguaSandra,could you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: <Button HeightRequested="{Binding Source={x:Reference frame}, Path=Height,  Converter={StaticResource frameHeight}, Converterparameter =2.5}"/>

Comment: Thank you @JessieZhang-MSFT!! Please in my xamarin page I have 3 frames I want to change heightrequested to fit screens, now I made the first frame which is my code above it works fine as expected, I achieved that by dividing ivalueconverter by 1.9 that's for the first frame, now what I want is how to make use of the same ivalueconverter class then change the 1.9 value from xamarin page without creating new class for the rest frames. Thanks

Comment: `I have 3 frames I want to change heightrequested to fit screens`  Which view‘s height do you want to change? And  where does the `ConverterParameter`'s value come from?